# Possible with x2x to have cut/paste work between Ubuntu PCs?

Tags: xorg, 20.10, synergy

My question is: has anyone successfully got cut/paste working over [x2x](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/X2xHowto) between two Ubuntu PCs? Is it possible? As I can't find any documentation/examples only a few references in articles saying it should/could/might work.

If it's not possible I would like to know if it's actually possible by other means (Barrier? Synergy?).

I already use x2x to control a Ubuntu 20.10 PC with my main PC's keyboard mouse (also Ubuntu 20.10) and it works great, but no cut/paste.

I read a few articles which say that if you start x2x using an alternative method (this needs some tweaks like `xhost` and other config to have tcp port 6000 listening) then cut/paste should work but although I can get x2x working with either method I have had no luck getting any sort of cut/paste working.

e.g. forwarding method:

`ssh -X remote_machinename_or_ip_address x2x -direction_of_the_remote_display -to :0`

and second alternative method:

`x2x -to IP_or_hostname:0.0 -direction_of_the_remote_display`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that either not many people use x2x and/or perhaps it's not possible to have cut/paste support with x2x.

So, to answer my own question I moved from x2x to [Barrier](https://github.com/debauchee/barrier) and I can confirm that this does support cut/paste. And of course there is a Windows version so it works Ubuntu/Ubuntu as well as Ubuntu/Windows.

It's a great bit of software and it can be used/configured manually via CLI or via the GUI.

Thoroughly recommended to anyone who wants to easily control multiple PC's/laptops on a desk with a single mouse/keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible to share mouse pointer, keyboard and cut and paste between machines over the network.

I've used Synergy for years and its a great way of combining multiple workstations with only a single keyboard and mouse.

https://symless.com/synergy